# webmachine access post body in *_perf_logger

Tags: erlang, mochiweb, webmachine

Attempting to intercept all the requests on webmachine API. I took a copy of **webmachine_perf_logger.erl** and changed to publish the {verb, resource, module}.

For the posts I'm also interested in BODY. Because the logging part in **webmachine_decision_core.erl** gets triggered in a different process

```
 respond(Code) ->
      ....
      spawn(fun() -> do_log(LogData) end),
```

I do not see how can I access the it.

Is there any way to access it or other alternative is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you experimented with the `finish_request` resource function (https://github.com/basho/webmachine/wiki/Resource-Functions#resource-functions)? Like any other resource function it receives the request data and a context. You could do something like:

```
finish_request(ReqData, Context) ->
    do_log(extract_log_data(ReqData, Context)),
    {true, ReqData, Context}.
```

This would log whatever you extract from request data and context for every request. Note that crashed requests might not call `finish_request`.

Comment: this is applicable just per *_resource. what I want is as cross-cutting concern. with finish_request I loose the monitoring if a new resource is added with no finish_request implemented

Comment: Oh, I see. Off my head I only know a cowboy solution for this ;)

Comment: Having said that.. you should have a look how `chef_wm` uses `finish_request`. Look into https://github.com/opscode/chef_wm/blob/master/src/chef_wm_base.erl and how other resources use `chef_wm_base`. Opscode did an amazing job with the `erchef` implementation.

Comment: Sounds like this is something interesting